# using evosuite from command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, evosuite

When I try to use the EvoSuite testing tool from the command line, I get the following error:

```
Fatal crash on main EvoSuite process. Class using seed 1428172877144. Configuration id : null 
java.lang.RunTimeExceptionConfiguration:Did not manage to automatically find tools.jar. Use –Dtools_jar_location = <path> properly 
    at org.evosuite.runtime.agent.ToolsJarLocator.getLoaderForToolsJar<ToolsJarLocator.java:71> ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na] 
    at org.evosuite.Evosuite.parseCommandLine<Evosuite.java:152> ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na] 
    at org.evosuite.Evosuite.main<Evosuite.java:304> ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: So...did you add the -D flag that the error message had kindly pointed out to you?

Comment: No, i type the command: **java -jar evosuite-0.1.1.jar** and I get the error. What should I add?

Comment: ...Why don't you add the flag?  It needs to point to the location of your tools.jar installation.

Comment: **java -jar evosuite-0.1.1.jar -Dtools_jar_location = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib"**  <br/>Is this correct? Now I get the error that there is one unrecognized input [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib  <br/> What should I change?

Comment: @Makoto the flag is -D? or it is -Dtools_jar_locator?

Comment: I am not finding the syntax to add the flag. I get a message that the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use your JDK to run Evosuite, not the JRE. That may mean either going into the JDK /bin dir and running from there or fully quantifying the executable java binary file when you run (JDK..../bin/java.exe on windows for example).

Answer (score 1):

Copy the tools.jar from JDK to your JRE lib folder...it worked for me..The problem, its not able to find the tools.jar.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Makoto, you need to use a -D option. Note: no space between variable name and assigned value, ie `-Dx=v` is OK, whereas `-Dx = v` is wrong. So:

`java -jar evosuite-0.1.1.jar -Dtools_jar_location="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib"`

Comment: thank you, but I get the same error message even when I remove the spaces!

Comment: setting -Dtools_jar_location had no effect, but Rajesh's answer worked